# MFC How to create a context menu with scrolling capability

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to create a context menu with scrolling capability because I need to insert a lot of file names on it, just like Visual Studio 2010's open files context menu.

[image: Context Menu with scrolling capability]

Anybody has any idea on how to implement this with MFC?

Comment: The built-in menus already do this. Notice that it isn't very user-friendly to have that many items in a menu. Explains why you don't see it very often. If you need to display this many items, at least put them in a list box that doesn't require so much mousing dexterity.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I didn't think about using list boxes. Good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows menu supports scrolling if you have more items than fit into the visible part. You can verify it by inserting a couple hundred items into your menu.

I guess the question should be: how to limit the vertical size of the menu (as it would otherwise extend to the height of your screen). Here is an example:

```
CMenu menu;
menu.CreatePopupMenu();
CString s;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
{
    s.Format(L"Item %.3d", i);
    menu.AppendMenu(MF_STRING, i, s);
}
MENUINFO mi = { sizeof(MENUINFO) };
mi.fMask = MIM_MAXHEIGHT;
mi.cyMax = 400;
menu.SetMenuInfo(&mi);
menu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_RETURNCMD, 100, 100, this);
```

Comment: You're right, the question is bad formulated, it should be "how to limit the vertical size of the menu".